# How to change classes while object oriented css with bem?

Tags: css, oop, sass

Well I'm watching videos about oop css with bem. I didn't understand one thing. I have a media object and I use it everywhere like in navbar and content and footer etc. So how shall I change the media object and insiders. I guess 3 ways there are.

1 - I can catch inside other blocks grandchild chooser
it will like ".navbar .media".

This way makes me worrying because of grandchildren is making slow and complicated I think. Don't think about only .media. I have to select media-item etc etc...

2 - I can give another class to .media like .navbar together
it will like ".navbar.media".

This way need more classes to html so it makes me thinking.

3 - I guess there is no third option if there is please let me know :) Which way I shall do.

Thank you already.

Comment: If you're worried about nested classes making things slower, I wouldn't. Look up "premature optimisation".

Comment: If you are talking about gzip, I know it.

How do you do guys? I have to figure out that thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an extra class, `navbar__media` (that's a double underscore for descendant), and add that to the media elements inside of the navbar.

A rule of BEM/OOP CSS is that an element should always have their style defined by the classes they have, and not based on where they are in the DOM.

For reference: http://getbem.com/naming/

Example:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="media navbar__media"></div>
</div>

<div class="media"></div>
```

With this css:

```css
.navbar {
  background: #00f;
} 

.media {
  background: #f00;
}

.navbar__media {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: You mean that I will create everything again and again inside different places? So If we won't change the original .media class, where is the oop part? 

Or you are talking about option 2 that I said? I will change the original class with .navbar__media.media?

Comment: Nope, you should not be joining classes, which is explained under "Element > CSS > Bad" at the link i posted. I've updated my answer with example HTML/CSS

Comment: Thank you for your effort :) but somehow I dont get it. Because If we use like that which class will work? Two classes and one property and they have equal strenght. I shall !important? Otherwise it does'nt work. The problem is reaching to the element. Your way is the third option :) So I m so confused.

Comment: Okay If the same property with two classes, the first class works more Strenght than the other. so I won't change the class .media

Somebody help meeeee :))) I really don't know what to do. m I right or not???

Comment: And `!important` doesn't have to be bad, read for example this extensive blogpost about using CSS at BBC sport